# iPhone Configuration Utility :- to add multiple web clips in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, web-clips

I am trying to create multiple web clips using iPhone configurator Utility.But when I try to add second webclip with different Label,URL and web clip icon it gets replaced with existing one.My question is,Is it possible to create multiple web clips using Configurator on iPhones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add multiple web clips you need to change the payload identifier.[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW34)
If you not rename this identifier, the older web clip which you created is replaced by the newer one.

Comment: Thanks Bro, u saved my time.It worked by changing payload identifier.